# Define Subgroup in Brian2 (library in python)

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried to test a spiking neural network in Python using Brian2. I received this error:

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\snn\lib\site-packages\brian2\groups\group.py", line 393, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError('No attribute with name ' + name)
```

AttributeError: No attribute with name subgroup

My main problem is in making a subgroup of `G` (`NeuronGroup`). The first subgroup is excitatory neurons and the second one is inhibitory neurons.

```
G = NeuronGroup(4000, model=eqs, threshold=Vt, reset=Vr)

Ge = G.subgroup(3200) # Excitatory neurons

Gi = G.subgroup(800) # Inhibitory neurons
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error? Thanks.
The code for this SNN (spiking neural network) is:

```
import brian2
from brian2 import *
from brian2 import start_scope

taum = 20 * ms # membrane time constant
taue = 5 * ms # excitatory synaptic time constant
taui = 10 * ms # inhibitory synaptic time constant
Vt = -50 * mV # spike threshold
Vr = -60 * mV # reset value
El = -49 * mV # resting potential
we = (60 * 0.27 / 10) * mV # excitatory synaptic weight
wi = (20 * 4.5 / 10) * mV # inhibitory synaptic weight
eqs = Equations('''
dV/dt = (ge-gi-(V-El))/taum : volt
dge/dt = -ge/taue : volt
dgi/dt = -gi/taui : volt
''')
G = NeuronGroup(4000, model=eqs, threshold=Vt, reset=Vr)
Ge = G.subgroup(3200) # Excitatory neurons
Gi = G.subgroup(800) # Inhibitory neurons
Ce = Connection(Ge, G, 'ge', sparseness=0.02, weight=we)
Ci = Connection(Gi, G, 'gi', sparseness=0.02, weight=wi)
M = SpikeMonitor(G)
MV = StateMonitor(G, 'V', record=0)
Mge = StateMonitor(G, 'ge', record=0)
Mgi = StateMonitor(G, 'gi', record=0)
G.V = Vr + (Vt - Vr) * rand(len(G))
run(500 * ms)

subplot(211)
raster_plot(M, title='The CUBA network', newfigure=False)
subplot(223)
plot(MV.times / ms, MV[0] / mV)
xlabel('Time (ms)')
ylabel('V (mV)')
show()
subplot(224)
plot(Mge.times / ms, Mge[0] / mV)
plot(Mgi.times / ms, Mgi[0] / mV)
xlabel('Time (ms)')
ylabel('ge and gi (mV)')
legend(('ge', 'gi'), 'upper right')
show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining subgroup in `Brian2` according to following:

For example we have p(neuron group) and we want to have two subgroup of it.

```
P = NeuronGroup(4000, model=eqs, threshold='v>-20*mV', refractory=3*ms, method='exponential_euler')

Pe = P[:3200]

Pi = P[3200:]
```

In my question I used instructions of Brian not Brian2! so I received error.
Be careful about using instruction of Brian2 and Brian!